# How to calculate the percentage to add to a increasing amount to get a total in a fixed time?

Tags: exponential-function, percentages

Let say I want to earn 2000€ with an investment done each day in a year (i.e. a percentage every day, for 365 days).
I have a initial budge of X amount.

Which percentage (per day) I have to gain to get +2000€ in a year?

For example, starting with a budget of 850€, which percentage of gain I need to use every day reaching that exact sum?
Of course, what I gain every day I'll re-invest the next day.

Its seems a sort of exponential percentage...

Comment: Do you know how to sum a geometric series?  If you get interest each day, that is what you have.

Comment: @RossMillikan its not linear. As said, "Of course, what I gain every day I'll re-invest the next day.". So if first day I have 1% of 850, next day I'll put 858,5 (which need a minor percentage), and so on...

Comment: This is just compound interest. You can look up the formula. Given the start and end values you can calculate the rate necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for example, let the percentage earned be 5%, the total amount be A, and the initial amount be X. After one day, the amount is $A = X + X*(0.05)$, or after factoring, $A = X(1.05)$. To get the amount after day 2, we can repeat this procedure to get $A = X(1.05)(1.05)$. Repeating, we get the formula $A = X(1.05)^{days}$

instead of dealing with 1.05, let p = the percentage + 1, so we have $A = X(p)^{days}$. Now let's solve the problem

You want an earned amount of 2000 after 365 days, so A-X = 2000 and A = X*p^365

Subtract X from both sides of the latter equation, to get
$$
    A-X = Xp^{365} - X
$$
but we know A-X is 2000, so
$$
    2000 = Xp^{365} - X
$$
rearranging for p, we get
$$
    \sqrt[365]{\frac{2000+X}{X}} = p
$$
or just
$$
    \sqrt[365]{\frac{2000+X}{X}} - 1 = percentage
$$

Comment: Uhm, so for init budget of 850€, the percentage I need to earn every day is 0,99081385979049153908138597904915? It seems so much at first look...

Comment: @markzzz for init budget of 850, I get a percentage of 0.0033201...%. Are you sure you did your math correctly?

Comment: You are right. But I think you need to multiply per 100, i.e. 0.33201% :)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that it is not linear, but you can use the formula $$FV = PV\left(1+\frac {r}{n}\right)^{nt}$$ where $FV = \text {future value} \\ PV = \text {present value} \\ r = \text {interest rate} \\ n = \text {number of times interest is compounded} \\ t = \text {length of time}$

and solve for $r$.

ETA: Per your request, $$r=\bigg(\bigg(\frac {FV}{PV}\bigg)^{\frac {1}{nt}}-1\bigg)$$ so $$r=\bigg(\bigg(\frac {2000+850}{850}\bigg)^{\frac {1}{365}}-1\bigg) \approx 0.00332 \ (0.332\%)$$

where $FV = 2850 \ (2000 + 850) \\ PV = 850 \\ n = 365 \ (\text {number of times interest is compounded}) \\ t = 1 \ (\text {one year})$

Comment: sorry but can't get the result out with my data. is Rate Percent = n[ ( (A/P)^(1/nt) ) - 1] * 100? I would say A = 2000+850, P = 850, but what is n? and t? Can you give the final formula with the data written in the main question please?

Comment: tried with excel, the Plaisk seems correct (0.33201%)

Comment: Done...see ETA above.

Comment: Uhm, It seems different than the Plaisk formula :O

Comment: Thanks for letting me know - corrected.

Comment: I think is still wrong? The correct percentage seems to be 0.33201. Tried with excel, dragging the resulta for each day, and got exactly 2850 after one year (with 0.33021%)

Comment: Got it.  I was calculating from 850 to 2000, but you were looking to add 2000 to the 850; also I didn't realize that t = 1.  Hopefully it's correct this time :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147356/discussion-between-bjcolby15-and-markzzz).